# filter rows by specifying the number in data grid using flex 4.5

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I'm using flex builder 4.5. A data grid displays 20 rows. I want to display the specified number of rows in data grid header. Is it possible to do? Can anyone advise on this?

Comment: Was the problem already closed? I'm not sure I have understood your task well. If you need another solution, explain your situation a little bit better, I'll try to find a way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by Binding a String to headerText property of grid column.

its look like

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    [Bindable]
    private var _personString:String = "";

    /*change this variable's value will change the value of Header Named 
    "fullNameColumn".if you want to make some default value then assign 
    some default value to this _perosnString varialbe.*/

]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:DataGrid id="personsDataGrid"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            selectedIndex="0">

    <s:columns>

        <s:ArrayList>

            <s:GridColumn id="fullNameColumn"
                          dataField="YOUR_FNAME_DATAFIELD"
                          headerText="{ _personString.toUpperCase() } NAME"
                          minWidth="100"
                          maxWidth="250" />

            <s:GridColumn headerText="PHONE"
                          dataField="YOUR_EMAIL_DATAFIELD"
                          minWidth="150"
                          maxWidth="250" />

            <s:GridColumn headerText="EMAIL"
                          dataField="YOUR_EMAIL_DATAFIELD"
                          minWidth="150"
                          maxWidth="250" />
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

May this will help you!!!